# GWTUploader add file on start

Tags: java, gwt

I use gwtupload (http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) and I need add on start files to this. Someone know how can I do it ?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear in your question, I dont understand what you mean with 'I need add on start files to this'

Comment: Ok. I create MultiUpload object and it don't have any files inside when you click browse files and select one you add it to this MultiUploader. My problem it's that I need add file when I create object and later user can delete this or add more.

Comment: Interesting question but I'm afraid you cannot achieve that. Either trying to add files from the user or adding yours is problematic because of security reasons.

Comment: I think that I can add exists files to Servlet HashTable (http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted)

Comment: Adding files to the servlet hash table doesn't modifies the ui. You need to implement a remote call to get the list of files uploaded in a previous session to the server, then you can show the files in the UI using some approach like I point in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can deduce that you want to add previously uploaded files to the multiuploader list.
There is no way with the current `MultiUploader`  although you can open a ticket at the project [site](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/issues/list), and I will implement it on a next release.

But you can extend the `MultiUploader` and code a workaround, this example works:

```
public class GwtTestApp implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    MyMultiUploader uploader = new MyMultiUploader("file1.txt", "file2.doc");
    RootPanel.get().add(uploader);
  }

  public static class MyMultiUploader extends MultiUploader {

    private VerticalPanel panel;
    private Widget multiuploader;

    @Override
    protected void initWidget(Widget widget) {
      panel = new VerticalPanel();
      super.initWidget(panel);
      multiuploader = widget;
    }

    public MyMultiUploader(String ...files) {

      for (String f : files ) {
        Uploader u = (Uploader)getUploaderInstance();
        IFileInput i = u.getFileInput();
        IUploadStatus s = u.getStatusWidget();

        i.setVisible(false);
        s.setVisible(true);
        u.getForm().removeFromParent();

        u.setServletPath("whatever");
        s.setFileName(f);
        s.setStatus(Status.SUCCESS);

        final String name = f;
        s.addCancelHandler(new UploadCancelHandler() {
          public void onCancel() {
            Window.alert("Cancel " + name);
          }
        });

        panel.add(u);
      }

      panel.add(multiuploader);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have another question. I set uploader.setMaximumFiles(2) but when I create uploader like in your example this parameter is omitted. Only if I add files in "normal" way this parameter works correctly.

Comment: I also need get file name after i click cancel button. I try create method but I dont know how get it automaticaly in other class where I can get this name.

Comment: setMaximumFiles should work, but be aware that it does not count the files you have added previously. You have the name in the method onCancel of the inner class in the example, so from this method you have to call the other class.

Comment: I badly explained. I have class where use MyMultiUploader like a object and in this class I want know on which the file user induce onCancel method...

Comment: I have idea how I can set maxFiles count (I get this value by getMaximumFiles method and change it depending on how much files I add) i need know how I can call IUploader.onCancelUploadHandler from MyMultiUploader class. I created o  IUploader cancel method I only need call it.

Comment: I resolved my problem. I create private variable IUploader.OnCancelUploaderHandler type and call method onCancel().

Answer (score 0):

I think that we need add files in servlet

```
Hashtable<String, String> receivedContentTypes = new Hashtable<String, String>();
/**
* Maintain a list with received files and their content types. 
*/
Hashtable<String, File> receivedFiles = new Hashtable<String, File>();
```

But I dont know how...